# why does the bootstrap navbar not work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the default bootstrap navbar work, but the toggle does not seem to work. I don't really know why:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="" class="navbar-brand">My Website</a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" datatoggle="collapse"
                data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36a7sjwq/)

Answer (score 3):

Check your code carefully next time :)

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" datatoggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```

Change `datatoggle` to `data-toggle`.